# What does this shell test achieve

Tags: bash, shell, virtualenv

I have a very simple question that I can't answer. In shell, what would this command do:

```
test -d $VIRTUAL_ENV || virtualenv $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

It seems like it tests if the virtualenv directory exists, but I dont understand what if does with that information. Will it always create the virtualenv afterwards, or would it only do it if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` is the OR condition. Hence, this will test if `$VIRTUAL_ENV` directory exists. If not, it will run `virtualenv $VIRTUAL_ENV`.

Other examples:

```
$ test -d /tmp || echo "yes"
$
$ test -d /tmpblabla || echo "this dir does not exist"
this dir does not exist
$ test -d /tmp && echo "/tmp exists" || echo "yes"
/tmp exists
```

Answer (score 1):

It tests if the directory `$VIRTUAL_ENV` exists and otherwise creates it using `virtualenv`